# Помощь со слайдером

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть слайдер, под центральным слайдом текст описывающий слайд, который должен меняться в зависимости от слайда, как лучше всего это реализовать?

P.S. пользуюсь slick slider если это имеет значение

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&subset=cyrillic');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.bgvideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -9999;
}
.screen{
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;   
    height: 100vh;    
}
#screen1{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 170px;
}
.logo{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 86px;
    width: 340px;
    background:url("../img/logo.png");
}
#screen1{
    color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
}
#screen1 h1{
    font-weight:500;
    font-size: 41pt;
    margin: 33px 0 0 0;
}
#screen1 h2{
    font-size: 22pt;
    font-weight: 300;
}
#screen1 button{
    cursor:pointer;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    font-size: 24pt;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
#screen1 button:hover{
        background: #fff;
        color:#222;
}
.bg{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -3vh;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90vh;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
#screen2{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 58px;
}
.active{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #222;
}
#screen2 h1{
    color:#222;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 27pt;
    font-weight: 400;
}
#screen2 h2{
    cursor: pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#222;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#screen2 h2:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #222;
}

.slick-slide img {
    width: 100%; 
}
.slider {
    width: 65%;
    margin: 25px auto;
}
.slick-slide {
    margin: 0px 20px;
}
.slider-img{

}
.slider-dsc{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.design{
    display: block;
}
.illustrations{
    display: none;
}
#screen3{
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    padding-top: 44px;
    color: #222;
    text-align: center;
    
}
#screen3 h1{
    padding-bottom: 21px;
    font-weight: 400; 
}
#screen3 h2{
    font-weight: 300;
}
.contact{
    margin-top: 91px;
}
textarea{
    resize: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    width: 460px;
    border: 2px solid #c8c8c8;
}
input[type="text"],input[type="email"]{
    border: 2px solid #c8c8c8;
    width: 217px;
    height: 28px;
}
input[type="submit"]{
    color: #222;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #41375b;
    width: 460px;
    height: 28p;
    font-size: 15pt;
}
input[type="submit"]:hover{
    background: #41375b;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="text"]{
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Xcurve</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css" />
    <link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> </head>

<body>
    <video autoplay loop muted class="bgvideo" id="bgvideo">
        <source src="img/background.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
    </video>
    <section class=screen id=screen1>
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <h1>design studio</h1>
        <h2>we make your life better</h2>
        <button>CLICK TO GO</button>
    </section>
    <section class=screen id=screen2>
        <div class="bg">
            <h1>PORTFOLIO</h1>
            <h2 id="btn1" class="active">DESIGN</h2>
            <h2 id="btn2">ILLUSTRATIONS</h2>
            <div class="slider-design slider design">
                <div class="sl_slide"><img src="Layer7.png" alt="image1"></div>
                <div class="sl_slide"><img src="Layer7.png" alt="image2"></div>
                <div class="sl_slide"><img src="Layer7.png" alt="image3"></div>
                <div class="sl_slide"><img src="Layer7.png" alt="image1"></div>
                <div class="sl_slide"><img src="Layer7.png" alt="image2"></div>
                <div class="sl_slide"><img src="Layer7.png" alt="image3"></div>
                <div class="sl_slide"><img src="Layer7.png" alt="image1"></div>
                <div class="sl_slide"><img src="Layer7.png" alt="image2"></div>
                <div class="sl_slide"><img src="Layer7.png" alt="image3"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-illustrations slider illustrations">
                <div class="sl_slide"><img src="Layer8.png" alt="image1"></div>
                <div class="sl_slide"><img src="Layer8.png" alt="image2"></div>
                <div class="sl_slide"><img src="Layer8.png" alt="image3"></div>
                <div class="sl_slide"><img src="Layer8.png" alt="image1"></div>
                <div class="sl_slide"><img src="Layer8.png" alt="image2"></div>
                <div class="sl_slide"><img src="Layer8.png" alt="image3"></div>
                <div class="sl_slide"><img src="Layer8.png" alt="image1"></div>
                <div class="sl_slide"><img src="Layer8.png" alt="image2"></div>
                <div class="sl_slide"><img src="Layer8.png" alt="image3"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-dsc">
                <div class="dsc1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo nulla, eum, reiciendis iste accusamus error fugiat qui perspiciatis minus. Facilis hic, veniam dolorem vero a.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class=screen id=screen3>
        <h1>SERVICES</h1>
        <h2>LOGO DESIGN</h2>
        <h2>IDENTITY</h2>
        <h2>ART ILLUSTRATIONS</h2>
        <h2>MENU LAYOUT</h2>
        <h2>WEB DESIGN</h2>
        <h1 class="contact">CONTACT US</h1>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required placeholder="Name">
            <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="E-mail">
            <textarea name="Massage" id="massage-field" placeholder="Massage" rows="8"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND MASSAGE"> 
        </form>
    </section>
    <script src="js/scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="js/timings.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./slick/slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.slider-design').slick({
                dots: true,
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                autoplay: false,
                autoplaySpeed: 2000,
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.slider-illustrations').slick({
                dots: true,
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                autoplay: false,
                autoplaySpeed: 2000,
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте beforeChange, для определения смены слайда и текста для него.
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/
Все колбеки прописаны на сайте разработчика )